# Disable extension for mobile theme

Tags: magento-1.8, theme, mobile, extensions

I have implemented an extension for my desktop theme, and I want to disable this extension on mobile theme (added as exception).

I know I can do this by creating separate store view for both themes but I don't want to define 2 store views.

Is there any way to implement this in the themes local.xml file or any other place?

Comment: Are you switching themes by user agent exceptions in "System > Configuration > Design"?

Comment: Modules are already loaded by the time a theme has been selected, so it is too late to disable it.  However you can do/undo certain actions per-theme.  Please expand your question to include specific changes you want to stop.

Comment: I am not switching themes, I have just added an exception for mobile theme.

Answer (score 1):

You can disable a module by creating an empty XML file in /mobile-theme/layout. This disables the output of the module. IE you will disable the Tag module in your mobile theme, you create an empty tag.xml file